# Why is my regex C++ expression not working?

Tags: c++, regex, function

I have the following regex expression: `\\(([^)]+)\\)` (don't take into account the double brackets it's because of C++) and the following code:

```
if (in_str.find("(") != string::npos) {
        print(to_string(countMatchInRegex(in_str, "\\([^ ]*\\.[^ ]*\\)")));
        for (int i = 0; i < countMatchInRegex(in_str, "\\(([^)]+)\\)"); ++i) {
            regex r("\\(([^)]+)\\)");
            smatch m;
            regex_search(in_str, m, r);
            string obj = m.str();
            obj = obj.substr(1, obj.length() - 2);
            string property = obj.substr(obj.find(".") + 1);
            obj = obj.substr(0, obj.find("."));
            in_str = replace(in_str, m.str(), process_property(obj, property));
        }
    }
```

This code is supposed to find, in a string, substrings like the following: (something.somethingelse). It works fine, except it only works two times...but i don't know how. I do know the problem is not the `countMatchInRegex` function, because I've printed what it results the correct number of substrings that match the regex expression in the string.
If anyone has any idea, please share them, I've been stuck on this for weeks..

Comment: I usually develop my regular expressions here https://regex101.com/ before using them in my C++ code (with proper extra escapes). Maybe that can help you find out if the problem is in the regex or somewhere else.

Comment: Use raw string literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the error, I don’t know why but C++ was returning different values for the two `countMatchInRegex` so all I did was assign it to a variable and use the variable instead every thing the function was called in the code.